disable CORS through chrome extension
There is a Chromium bug which breaks webRequest.onAuthRequired handler if HTTPS CONNECT web proxy is set and website is doing preflight OPTIONS requests - https://issues.chromium.org/issues/359904347.
I need a temporary (hopefully) workaround to this and one idea I have is disabling CORS for specific domains/urls. Is it possible via extension?
I've thought about setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * via chrome.declarativeNetRequest API, but it doesn't solve the problem, the OPTIONS requests are still made and onAuthRequired is still not triggered. Is disabling CORS possible some other way? Or maybe some other workaround can help?

try https://mitmproxy.org/ or https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere
